# No Plug-In available for application Silverlight 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, plugins, silverlight-3.0

I have Asp.Net MVC application I have added Silverlight web app inside one of View Page of MVC. In my Silverlight app I have images that slides inside Border after a certain number of milliseconds.

I want to merge that application inside one of the page of MVC.

The problem is I can only see the Border and not the images that are embedded inside it.

Every browser says that No Plug-Ins are available for application. I installed and checked that plug-Ins for SL are available, still getting the same error message.
I am using SL-3

I am using this inside Index.aspx page of MVC View:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-3," type="application/x-silverlight-3" width="400" height="300"> 
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
    <param name="background" value="Red" />
</object>
```

Comment: You post no code, I'm not sure how we can help.

Comment: I am using this inside Index.aspx page of MVC View.           <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-3," type="application/x-silverlight-3" width="400" height="300">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
    <param name="background" value="Red" />
    </object>

Comment: http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/simple-image-scroller-slide-show-using-silverlight-listbox-control/                                         Thats exactly my Silverlight App is doing...

Comment: Please don't include code is comments, as you can see its very ugly, just edit your question and include the additional details.

Answer (score 1):

These attributes:-

```
data="data:application/x-silverlight-3," type="application/x-silverlight-3"
```

are wrong, they should be:-

```
data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
```

In order to ensure it runs on silverlight 3 add:-

```
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
```

Comment: I tried above...result is improved and i can see the Border only but not images that are embedded inside it. Though SL app works fine if i set SL as a StartUp project ...

Comment: @rehan88: Have you used Fiddler to examine exactly what the client is attempting to fetch from the server?  For example are you sure the path "ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap" is correct relative your page.  Since you are using MVC I suspect it isn't, perhaps you need an absolute path "/ClientBin..."

Comment: Both ClientBin and Home has same parent directory(Views). Home has About.aspx and Index.aspx. So in Index.aspx i have object tag. I am now writing path like "../ClientBin/SilverlightApplication.xap"

Comment: @rehan88:  However in MVC the url addresses the Controller not the view.  The browser has no understanding of the MVC, it will compose the request for the XAP based on the URL __that it is seeing__ of the host page.